# Any phalcon vs chicagoboss benchmarks?

Tags: performance, comparison, phalcon, chicagoboss

These frameworks are the future of speed internet. But I can't find any benchmark or feature comparison of them on google. What framework in which situation would be better for example for building highload online shop? For building stackoverflow clone?

Maybe some basic memory management and request handling differences explanation, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the [official documentation](https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/ChicagoBoss/wiki) links to [techempower](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/), ChicagoBoss is not mentioned anywhere. Looking closely at ChicagoBoss it seems to be targeted mostly at Erlang developers, which is not the most popular language out there. I'm a fanatical about Phalcon, but I feel that ChicagoBoss would be faster and more resource efficient out of the box. But… writing your entire app in binary code right away would be even better in that sense.

Phalcon in less than two years achieved bigger popularity and reputation than ChicagoBoss did in five. There is significantly more information and support out there for Phalcon given all standard PHP rules and information apply to it as well. Phalcon next big release is under active development and looks very promising.

> What framework in which situation would be better for example for
>   building highload online shop? For building stackoverflow clone?

I'm certain that neither Amazon or SO use either of them but both rely on a lot of caching and infrastructure optimisation to get where they are – the job for a different type framework.

Phalcon is a great lightweight tool for building unique projects with focus on high performance. It behaves very nicely with PhpStorm and the development / debugging is a pleasure most of the time. But be sure, it will give a lot of headache (there are a few bugs and some information is hard to come by) – isn't the best choice for enterprise software, you will spend a lot of time figuring out how things work and how to fix some of them.

Comment: Thank you so much, very good answer with practical usage recommendations.